# Toshiba external hard disk 2 tb undetected by pc however blinking

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, toshiba-hard-drive

Suddenly my TOSHIBA EXTERNAL HDD fall down a small distance later i tried to connect it to pc but it keeps blinking or flashing and the windows makes sound like recognizing usb but it’s not showing on my pc i tried all tools and programs to initialize the unallocated space which has been created but still no hope
I tried to rebuild a MBR but it’s useless as a msg appears to error can’t initialize an unallocated space
I tried all steps on internet but no clue , it does appear on disk
management and device manager

Comment: Hardware failures CAN'T be corrected by software. Everything you did can only make things worse.

Comment: But how can i know the difference between hardware and software problems, honestly in between i had the feeling that i am getting everything worse

Comment: It's damaged so it's hardware. Either the USB controller or the disk itself or both. You may try open it and put the disk in a generic enclosure.